# Android save working bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, save

I have a Bitmap that I chose from gallery that is getting edited
like putting on it stickers, adjusting hue, brightness ..
putting colors etc..
It's a photo editing app...
It's all working fine, my last problem is
How do I make the Bitmap saves so it goes to the next activity

like,,

In my last activity where u share the image u made, there is an imageview, and it's working it shows the bitmap that u imported form the gallery but it's not editied
like it shows the original Bitmap
not the one I edited it..

How do I make when they click the button done in the editing activity the `currentBitmap` gets saved so in the share activity where done will take them it shows what they did

Comment: where you want to save the edited image. inside your database or in the gallery of the phone memory??

Comment: See the link. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11734768/1395259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
//create a class in your package
class objectclass{
  public static Bitmap bmp;
}

//save your previous activity bitmap like this
....
objectclass.bmp = b;//your bitmap
....

//use in another activity like this
Bitmap b1 = objectclass.bmp;
```

hope help